# Tomcat server is only accessible from localhost

Tags: tomcat, localhost, windows-server

I have installed tomcat 8.0 in a windows server 2012. Tomcat is working if I access him through localhost:8080. But if I try to access him through IP:8080 there is a message 'This webpage is not available'. Is not working also from outside of the server. I changed server.xml, I added address="ip of the machine" and  address="0.0.0.0" I also opened port 8080 to firewall. Each time I made a change I restareted tomcat. Also If I write ipconfig /all in cmd in IpV4 adress I don't get IP of the machine but 10.1.5.

Comment: Do you have response pinging that IP address?

Comment: No. Not from inside the server or outside the server

Comment: If ping response is not reachable, then you should check for network problem first.

Comment: What do you mean? I am sorry but I am new to this.

Comment: 1) please share the relevant part of server.xml (2) is this server bound to more than 1 IP address? (3) Can you access tomcat using the 10.1.5.x IP?

Comment: Try ping x:x:x:x from client machine and check the response. Also telnet the port, post both responses here

Comment: I spoke with administrators and there was another firewall (cloud firewall) that I couldn't change (I didn't have permissions) so they gave me another port that was open. Thank you everyone for your responses